# Basic Set-Theoretic Properties from Halmos

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I've been backtracking lately to make sure that I have a solid set-theoretic background before taking measure theory this fall. Here's a few facts I've come across today, and my attempted proofs. Let me know how they may be improved, or if they are incorrect.
Suppose all sets are contained in a universal set $\mathscr{U}$.

**I:** $A \cap (B \setminus C) = ( A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C)$
*Proof:*
Suppose $( A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C)$ is non-empty. $$\begin{align*}
 ( A \cap B) \setminus (A \cap C) &= (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)^c \\
&= (A \cap B) \cap (A^c \cup C^c) \\
&= (A \cap B) \cap (C^c) \\
&= A \cap (B \cap C^c) \\
&= A \cap (B \setminus C)
\end{align*}$$

**II:** $A \cap B \subset (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C^c)$
*Proof:*
$$\begin{align*}
A \cap B &= A \cap (B \cap \mathscr{U}) \\
&= A \cap (B \cap (C^c \cup C))\\
&= A \cap ((B \cap C^c) \cup (B \cap C)) \\
&= (A \cap B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C) \\
&\subset (B \cap C^c) \cup (A \cap C)
\end{align*}$$

**III:** $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C^c) \subset A \cup B$

*Proof:*

$$\begin{align*}
(A \cap B)^c \supset ((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C^c))^c
\end{align*}$$
which implies
$$\begin{align*}
(A^c \cup B^c) \supset ((A^c \cup C^c) \cap (B^c \cup C))
\end{align*}$$
replacing all sets by their complements yields the result.

**IV:** $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$
*Proof:*

Suppose $A \setminus (A \setminus B)$ is non-empty.

$$\begin{align*}
A \setminus (A \setminus B) &= A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c \\
&= A \cap (A^c \cup B) \\
& = A \cap B
\end{align*}$$

**V:**
$A \setminus (B \setminus A) \supset A \setminus B$

*Proof:*
$$\begin{align*}
A \setminus (B \setminus A) &= A \cap (B^c \cup A) \\
&= (A \cap B^c) \cup A \\
&\supset A \setminus B
\end{align*}$$

Moreover, can anyone suggest anymore set-theoretic concepts and exercises that will prove useful in measure theory? i.e. knowing how to write countable unions as disjoint unions, etc.

Comment: In "V", I would have said $(A \cap B^c) \cup A = A \supset A\setminus B $